# IOS/Swift:syntax to return custom object in closure

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I would like to place some JSON obtained asynchronously in an object and return in a closure.  My code however is giving an error.

```
func postToWebSwervice (aString:String,completion:@escaping (_ response:Array<Any>)->(MyObject)){
//get some JSON from web
let myObject = MyObject()
//parse JSON
myObject.title = "Palo Alto"
myObject.temp = 62

DispatchQueue.main.async {//open async
                       completion( myObject )
                    }
}
```

I am getting an error: `'Cannot convert object of type myObject to closure result type Void (aka ())`

I gather you cannot 'return' object.  But what would correct syntax be to make it available to calling method upon completion?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Your completion block's data type is `Array<Any>` while you are passing `MyObject()` type. Please check closure docs first how the structure works. A good resource is - http://fuckingclosuresyntax.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Array<Any>` with `MyObject` (you need to change your completion block syntax like thi)

```
func postToWebSwervice (aString:String,completion:@escaping (_ response: MyObject)-> Void){
    //get some JSON from web
    let myObject = MyObject()
    //parse JSON
    myObject.title = "Palo Alto"
    myObject.temp = 62

    DispatchQueue.main.async {//open async
        completion( myObject )
    }
}
```